# Subspace of $l^2$ such that is not closed.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Find a subspace $Y \subseteq l^2$ such that $Y$ is not closed.

Define $Y=\{ x=(x_n)\in l^2 \vert x_n=0 \hspace{0.5mm} \text{except for a finite number of indices}\}$

Note that $Y \neq l^2 $.

Let $x=(x_n)\in l^2$ and define $y_n=(x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n, 0, \ldots )\in Y$.

$\textbf{Claim:}$ $y_n \rightarrow x$

Indeed, we have $$\Vert y_n - x \Vert = \sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty} \vert x_j \vert^2 $$

How $$\Vert x \Vert^2= \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \vert x_k \vert^2 $$

For each $\epsilon >0$ exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ $$ \implies\Vert x  \Vert^2 - \sum_{j=1}^{n} \vert x_j \vert^2 < \epsilon$$

So for $n>N$ $$\Vert y_n - x \Vert = \sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty} \vert x_j \vert^2=\Vert x  \Vert^2 - \sum_{j=1}^{n} \vert x_j \vert^2 < \epsilon$$

Then $\overline{Y} = l^2$ and so $Y$ is not closed.

It´s correct my solution?

Comment: Yes, it is correct to show $Y \subsetneq \overline Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that works.  You might expend a word or two, but just a word or two, indicating why $Y$ is a linear subspace of $l^2$.